# Replace all zeros in vector by previous non-zero value

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, octave, vectorization

Matlab/Octave algorithm example:

```
 input vector: [ 1 0 2 0 7 7 7 0 5 0 0 0 9 ]
output vector: [ 1 1 2 2 7 7 7 7 5 5 5 5 9 ]
```

The algorithm is very simple: it goes through the vector and replaces all zeros with the last non-zero value. It seems trivial, and is so when done with a slow for (i=1:length) loop and being able to refer to the previous element (i-1), but looks impossible to be formulated in the fast vectorized form.
I tried the merge() and shift() but it only works for the first occurrence of zero, not an arbitrary number of them.

Can it be done in a vectorized form in Octave/Matlab or must C be used for this to have sufficient performance on big amount of data?

---

I have [another similar slow for-loop algorithm to speed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046161) and it seems generally impossible to refer to previous values in a vectorized form, like an SQL `lag()` or `group by` or `loop (i-1)` would easily do. But Octave/Matlab loops are terribly slow.

Has anyone found a solution to this general problem or is this futile for fundamental Octave/Matlab design reasons?

---

Performance benchmark:

### SOLUTION 1 (slow loop)

```
in = repmat([ 1 0 2 0 7 7 7 0 5 0 0 0 9 ] ,1 ,100000);
out = in;
tic
for i=2:length(out) 
   if (out(i)==0) 
      out(i)=out(i-1);
   end
end
toc
[in(1:20); out(1:20)] % test to show side by side if ok
```

Elapsed time is 15.047 seconds.

### SOLUTION 2 by Dan (~80 times faster)

```
in = V = repmat([ 1 0 2 0 7 7 7 0 5 0 0 0 9 ] ,1 ,100000);
tic;
d = double(diff([0,V])>0);
d(find(d(2:end))+1) = find(diff([0,~V])==-1) - find(diff([0,~V])==1);
out = V(cumsum(~~V+d)-1);
toc;
[in(1:20); out(1:20)] % shows it works ok
```

Elapsed time is 0.188167 seconds.

15.047 / 0.188167 = 79.97 times improvement

### SOLUTION 3 by GameOfThrows (~115 times faster)

```
in = repmat([ 1 0 2 0 7 7 7 0 5 0 0 0 9 ] ,1 ,100000);
a = in;
tic;
pada = [a,888];
b = pada(pada >0);
bb = b(:,1:end-1);
c = find (pada==0);
d = find(pada>0);
len = d(2:end) - (d(1:end-1));
t = accumarray(cumsum([1,len])',1);
out = bb(cumsum(t(1:end-1)));
toc;
```

Elapsed time is 0.130558 seconds.

15.047 / 0.130558 = 115.25 times improvement

### **Magical** SOLUTION 4 by Luis Mendo **(~250 times faster)**

```
in = repmat([ 1 0 2 0 7 7 7 0 5 0 0 0 9 ] , 1, 100000);
tic;
u = nonzeros(in);
out = u(cumsum(in~=0)).';
toc;
```

Elapsed time is 0.0597501 seconds.

15.047 / 0.0597501 = 251.83 times improvement

---

### (Update 2019/03/13) Timings with MATLAB R2017a:

```
Slow loop:    0.010862 seconds.
Dan:          0.072561 seconds.
GameOfThrows: 0.066282 seconds.
Luis Mendo:   0.032257 seconds.
fillmissing:  0.053366 seconds.
```

So we draw yet again the same conclusion: loops in MATLAB are no longer slow!

---

See also:
[Trivial/impossible algorithm challenge in Octave/Matlab Part II: iterations memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046161)

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? The loops really aren't slow anymore (for some years now) since they implemented the JIT compiler.

Comment: Also are the numbers between the zeros always the same or would this also be a possible input `[ 1 0 2 0 7 8 7 0 5 0 0 0 9 ]`?

Comment: @Dan I think this can be done, no?

Comment: Thx Dan. I'm using Octave 3.8.2 - the newest in Debian stable distro - and loops are thousands times slower than vectorized pieces ("warning: jit_enable: JIT compiling not available"). The numbers between zeros are arbitrary doubles, can be regarded random. The blocks of zeros are pre-set and can be changed to anything like NaN's or Inf's, because they are the places in the vector which were left unpopulated by the previous algorithm and hence need to get filled like described.

Comment: @GameOfThrows yes I think so. Just added my attempt

Comment: @Pawel could you do a `timeit` comparison between the two answers and a naive `for`-loop solution in your Octave for us? It will be interesting to see if these options give any performance improvements

Comment: @Dan sure working on it

Comment: @Pawel probably easier to use `isequal` than `[in(1:20); out(1:20)] # test to show side by side if ok`.

Comment: @Dan thx for the tip, one can learn a lot from you guys

Comment: @Pawel Can you also try Luis Mendo's solution, which I suspect should be the fastest, and also the cleanest.

Comment: @Pawel, I posted another solution, which I'd assume to be fast as well. Could you include it in your benchmark?

Comment: @thewaywewalk Thanks for your solution! Of course - I will run it and include it in the benchmark - as soon as I get my hands on the same system, today if possible

Comment: @Pawel don't worry I benched it myself (see my answer)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following simple approach does what you want, and is probably very fast:

```
in = [1 0 2 0 7 7 7 0 5 0 0 0 9];
t = cumsum(in~=0);
u = nonzeros(in);
out = u(t).';
```

Comment: Luis, there's a new function `fillmissing` since R2016b, your solution is faster than that. :) -- Of course, the plain old loop is now about 3 times faster than your solution... :)

Answer (score 7):

I think it is possible, let's start with the basics, you want to capture where number is greater than 0:

```
 a = [ 1 0 2 0 7 7 7 0 5 0 0 0 9 ] %//Load in Vector
 pada = [a,888];  %//Pad A with a random number at the end to help in case the vector ends with a 0
 b = pada(find(pada >0)); %//Find where number if bigger than 0
 bb = b(:,1:end-1);     %//numbers that are bigger than 0
 c = find (pada==0);   %//Index where numbers are 0
 d = find(pada>0);     %//Index where numbers are greater than 0
 length = d(2:end) - (d(1:end-1));  %//calculate number of repeats needed for each 0 trailing gap.
 %//R = [cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x,nx) repmat(x,1,nx), bb, length,'uniformoutput',0))]; %//Repeat the value

 ----------EDIT--------- 
 %// Accumarray and cumsum method, although not as nice as Dan's 1 liner
 t = accumarray(cumsum([1,length])',1);
 R = bb(cumsum(t(1:end-1)));
```

NOTE: I used `arrayfun`, but you can use `accumarray` as well.I think this demonstrates that it is possible to do this in parallel?

```
R =
```

Columns 1 through 10

```
 1     1     2     2     7     7     7     7     5     5
```

Columns 11 through 13

```
 5     5     9
```

TESTs:

```
a = [ 1 0 2 0 7 7 7 0 5 0 0 0 9 0 0 0 ]

R =
```

Columns 1 through 10

```
 1     1     2     2     7     7     7     7     5     5
```

Columns 11 through 16

```
 5     5     9     9     9     9
```

PERFORMANCE:

```
a = repmat([ 1 0 2 0 7 7 7 0 5 0 0 0 9 ] ,1,10000); %//Double of 130,000
Arrayfun Method : Elapsed time is 6.840973 seconds.
AccumArray Method : Elapsed time is 2.097432 seconds.
```

Comment: How does this compare with a simple `for`-loop though in terms of performance time though? `arrayfun` doesn't really count as vectorization. It would be interesting to compare as I don't know if it has an edge over loops because the OP is using Octave and doesn't get JIT benefits. The comparison would have to be done in Octave though.

Comment: I think it is possible to do it with `accumarray` and `cumsum` combined. Let me update this

Answer (score 7):

I think is a vectorized solution. Works on your example:

```
V = [1 0 2 0 7 7 7 0 5 0 0 0 9]
%// This is where the numbers you will repeat lie. You have to cast to a double otherwise later when you try assign numbers to it it caps them at logical 1s
d = double(diff([0,V])>0)
%// find(diff([0,~V])==-1) - find(diff([0,~V])==1) is the length of each zero cluster
d(find(d(2:end))+1) = find(diff([0,~V])==-1) - find(diff([0,~V])==1)
%// ~~V is the same as V ~= 0
V(cumsum(~~V+d)-1)
```

Comment: Also, I padded a non-zero number at the end of V, if you don't it does not work for when V ends in 0; I think.

Comment: @GameOfThrows also true. This will error in that case `find(diff([0,~V])==-1) - find(diff([0,~V])==1)`

Answer (score 6):

Here is another solution, using [**linear interpolation with previous neighbor lookup**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html).

I assume it to be quite fast as well, as there are just look-ups and indexing and no calculations:

```
in = [1 0 2 0 7 7 7 0 5 0 0 0 9]
mask = logical(in);
idx = 1:numel(in);
in(~mask) = interp1(idx(mask),in(mask),idx(~mask),'previous');
%// out = in
```

### Explanation

You need to create an index vector:

```
idx = 1:numel(in)  $// = 1 2 3 4 5 ...
```

And a logical mask, masking all your non-zero values:

```
mask = logical(in);
```

This way you get the grid points `idx(mask)` and grid data `in(mask)` for the interpolation. The query points `idx(~mask)` are indices of the zero data. The query data `in(~mask)` is then "calculated" by *next previous neighbor* interpolation, so it basically looks in the grid what is the value for the previous grid point. Exactly what you want. Unfortunately the involved functions have a huge overhead for all thinkable cases, thats why it is still slower than Luis Mendo's Answer, though there are no arithmetic calculations involved.

---

Furthermore one could reduce the overhead of `interp1` a little:

```
F = griddedInterpolant(idx(mask),in(mask),'previous');
in(~mask) = F(idx(~mask));
```

But there is not too much effect.

---

```
in =   %// = out

     1     1     2     2     7     7     7     7     5     5     5     5     9
```

---

### Benchmark

```
0.699347403200000 %// thewaywewalk
1.329058123200000 %// GameOfThrows
0.408333643200000 %// LuisMendo
1.585014923200000 %// Dan
```

**Code**

```
function [t] = bench()
    in = repmat([ 1 0 2 0 7 7 7 0 5 0 0 0 9 ] ,1 ,100000);

    % functions to compare
    fcns = {
        @() thewaywewalk(in);
        @() GameOfThrows(in);
        @() LuisMendo(in);
        @() Dan(in);
    }; 

    % timeit
    t = zeros(4,1);
    for ii = 1:10;
        t = t + cellfun(@timeit, fcns);
    end
    format long
end

function in = thewaywewalk(in) 
    mask = logical(in);
    idx = 1:numel(in);
    in(~mask) = interp1(idx(mask),in(mask),idx(~mask),'previous');
end
function out = GameOfThrows(a) 
    pada = [a,888];
    b = pada(find(pada >0));
    bb = b(:,1:end-1);
    c = find (pada==0);
    d = find(pada>0);
    length = d(2:end) - (d(1:end-1));
    t = accumarray(cumsum([1,length])',1);
    out = bb(cumsum(t(1:end-1)));
end
function out = LuisMendo(in) 
    t = cumsum(in~=0);
    u = nonzeros(in);
    out = u(t).';
end
function out = Dan(V) 
    d = double(diff([0,V])>0);
    d(find(d(2:end))+1) = find(diff([0,~V])==-1) - find(diff([0,~V])==1);
    out = V(cumsum(~~V+d)-1);
end
```

Answer (score 4):

New in MATLAB R2016b: [`fillmissing`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fillmissing.html), it does exactly as described in the question:

```
in = [ 1 0 2 0 7 7 7 0 5 0 0 0 9 ];
in(in==0) = NaN;
out = fillmissing(in,'previous');
```

[This new functionality discovered in [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55128371/7328782)].

Answer (score 2):

Vector operations generally assume independence of the individual items. If you have a dependence on an earlier item, then looping is the best way to do it.

Some extra background on matlab: In matlab the operations are typically faster not because of vector operations specifically, but because a vector operation simply does the loop in native C++ code instead of through the interpreter

Comment: but the input vector is given at the beginning and each update does not depend on the previous update. So technically you should be able to do this without a loop.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. Also, this problem is vertorizable in the MATLAB sense.