# Trivial/impossible algorithm challenge in Octave/Matlab - iterations memory

Tags: algorithm, performance, matlab, octave, vectorization

There is an input vector with allowed set of values `{-2,-1,0,1,2}`, e.g.

```
input = [2 2 2 2 0 1 0 -1 0 -2 -2 -1 0 1]
```

Vector is scanned iteratively from start to end and at each point a certain transition table is realized, based on the current value of the vector, and a certain accumulated value determined by previous iterations. This value is incremented/decremented by a requested step (3 here) up to the top value (9 here) beyond which it cannot go.
The output vector represents certain ongoing deltas derived out of the current input value and accumulation, according to the defined transitions.

The loop in Octave (3.8) performs very poorly and I cannot find a way to vectorize this. Is vectorization possible at all when such indirect memory of accumulation is used in between input and output?

```
input = [2 2 2 2 0 1 0 -1 0 -2 -2 -1 0 1] 
step  = 3;
top   = 9;
acc = out = 0;

for i = 1 : length(input) 
  if     (input(i) == +2) 
          if (acc <         0) out(i) = -acc+step; 
      elseif (acc >  top-step) out(i) = 0; 
      elseif (acc >=        0) out(i) = step; 
       endif 
  elseif (input(i) == +1) 
          if (acc >=        0) out(i) = 0; 
      elseif (acc <         0) out(i) = -acc; 
       endif 
  elseif (input(i) ==  0)      out(i) = 0; 
  elseif (input(i) == -1) 
          if (acc <=        0) out(i) = 0; 
      elseif (acc >         0) out(i) = -acc; 
       endif 
  elseif (input(i) == -2) 
          if (acc >         0) out(i) = -acc-step; 
      elseif (acc < -top+step) out(i) = 0; 
      elseif (acc <=        0) out(i) = -step; 
       endif 
  endif 
  acc += out(i);
endfor
out

out =
3 3 3 0 0 0 0 -9 0 -3 -3 0 0 6
# e.g. the -9 resets the first three 3's buildup: 3+3+3-9=0
```

Performance bechmark:

---

### Solution 1 (slow loop)

(EDITED)

```
input = repmat([2 2 2 2 0 1 0 -1 0 -2 -2 -1 0 1], 1,20000);
out   = zeros(1, length(input));
tic; for i = 1 : length(input) 
  (...)
endfor; toc;
Elapsed time is 8.95053 seconds.
```

Comment: well one of the big issues with why your loop may be slow is that you are not pre-allocating memory for your `out` vector, Other than that, since your logic is relies on previous processing, vectorization is a bit more complicated

Comment: @MZimmerman6 and Oleg thx for the hint, you are right, although it does not help much (`8.95/9.37 ~= 5%`) . I actually do it in the target program, forgot to use it for the purpose of this example. Will update now

Comment: @Pawel Keep in mind as well that you are doing 280000 iterations.With MATLAB/Octave being an interpreted language, this could be fairly slow. If you really need speed improvements, try writing the function in something that is compiled and then call it from Octave/MATLAB. This should improve speed dramatically.

Comment: @MZimmerman6 Yup, that would be my second best alternative - to rewrite this in C, and it would definitely be very fast then. I was hoping this could be avoided though, and kept as vectorized Octave, which is much more convenient from dev/depl standpoint. Already today I posted another algorithm I thought is not doable, and the answer is just amazingly clean and fast: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041614/trivial-impossible-algorithm-challenge-in-octave-matlab. Hope such exists for this problem too.

Comment: @Pawel Yes the other problem you posted is much simpler. Because this one relies on having an accumulation it is a bit more difficult

Comment: I must admit this is a fun one.  The key is to identify a series of steps that can create acc as a vector. Generally with vectorizing the job is to eliminate those temporary holding variables, or create them in one step. the -2 +2 parts aren't that hard, as cumsum can be used to find their desired step contribution, max() and min() can be used to clip them at +/-top.  abs(min(0,acc)) or the same with max can get the intent of the -1 +1 parts... perhaps abs(min(0,sign(acc))) would get a multiplicative vector for sign flipping... then using selective assignment to out with find...  hmmmm...

Comment: @NickJ thanks for the hints, maybe this is the right path? I will try working with these. Seems like definitely there must be a cumulative sum lurking somewhere in the solution :)