# Replace zeros with following nonzero value in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, replace, zero

I have a vector `A`, which contains values that are `zeros`. I would now like to replace all `zeros` with the following non-zero value. I found this [solution by @Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041614/replace-all-zeros-in-vector-by-previous-non-zero-value) to replace zeros with the previous non-zero values.

```
A = [1 0 2 0 7 7 7 0 5 0 0 0 9];
t = cumsum(A~=0);
u = nonzeros(A);
B = u(t).';
```

Is there a similar way to replace the `zeros` with the closest following non-zero value as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to apply the code to a flipped version of `A` and then flip the result:

```
A = [1 0 2 0 7 7 7 0 5 0 0 0 9];
t = cumsum(flip(A)~=0);
u = nonzeros(flip(A));
B = flip(u(t).');
```

Or, as noted by [@craigim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2183515/craigim), in recent Matlab versions you can use the `'reverse'` flag in `cumsum`:

```
A = [1 0 2 0 7 7 7 0 5 0 0 0 9];
t = cumsum(A ~= 0, 'reverse');
u = nonzeros(flip(A));
B = u(t).';
```

Comment: If your version of MATLAB is new enough, you could also do `t = cumsum(A ~= 0, 'reverse');`

Comment: @craigim Good idea! Edited