# Matlab: slower execution although less operation

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I'm new to Matlab. This is my playground script:

```matlab
function speedtest()
    a = reshape(1:1:30000, 10000, 3);

    tic;
    for i = 1:100
        a(:, [1, 2]) = bsxfun(@minus, a(:, [1, 2]), [1, 1]);
    end
    toc

    tic;
    for i = 1:100
        a = bsxfun(@minus, a, [1, 1, 0]);
    end
    toc
end
```

And the execution time:

```sh
Elapsed time is 0.007709 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.001803 seconds.
```

The first method has less operation, but it runs much slower. Is this a vectorization issue? If so, why can't Matlab "vectorize" my `a(:, [1, 2])` selection?

**Update:**

As per @thewaywewalk, I put the code to individual function, remove the loop and use `timeit`. Here's the result:

```sh
# a(:, [1, 2]) = bsxfun(@minus, a(:, [1, 2]), [1, 1]);
1.0064e-04

# a = bsxfun(@minus, a, [1, 1, 0]);
6.4187e-05
```

Comment: Using `tic` and `toc` is not the appropriate method to benchmark run times. Have a look at the `timeit` function or the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34059960/2605073). If the difference persists, we can discuss this here.

Comment: Additionally, this is an incorrect test, as you don't have the same starting conditions. You change `a` in the first loop, and do not reset it before you execute the second.

Comment: @thewaywewalk So `tic` and `toc` aren't monotonic? I'll do it again now.

Comment: @MinhNghĩa no, they just measure the real time between their calls, but thats not a fair comparison, as the execution engine of Matlab optimizes the program on runtime, especially if a functions is called multiple times. Thats why there is a dedicated timing function, which allows a fair comparison.

Comment: With "trivial" operations like minus, the cost for indexing becomes substantial. You could include the indexing operation like `c = a(:,1:2);` into your benchmark for reference. I guess the runtime is substantial compared to the complete code. With more recent MATLAB-Versions, you could also try broadcasting (`a = a -  [1, 1, 0];` and `a(:,1:2) = a(:,1:2) -  [1, 1];`) Might be faster, don't know.

Comment: As @Daniel suggest, the cost is in the indexing. You copy data out of `a` into a new matrix, apply the operation, then copy the result back in.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Sorry for keep you waiting. Should I include the loop in the function?

Comment: No, don’t put the loop in the function. `timeit` figures out how often to call your function to get a good time estimate.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Could you explain why it has to copy the first 2 columns into a new matrix, but not in the second method?

Comment: In the second method there is no indexing, hence no copying. It uses the whole matrix. MATLAB needs to make a copy when you use a subset of a matrix.

Comment: this is an interesting benchmark - I used to think creating matrix operations via `repmat` could be faster, but it turns out to be a lot slower than `bsxfun`. The command `a(:, [1, 2]) = a (:,[1,2])-repmat([1,1],size(a,1),1);` is order of magnitude slower than the bottom one.

Answer (score 1):

the overhead of the first approach came from sub-matrix slicing. changing it to

```
    tic;
    b=a(:,[1,2]);
    for i = 1:100
        b = bsxfun(@minus, b, [1, 1]);
    end
    a(:,[1,2])=b;
    toc
```

makes it significantly faster

Comment: This is somewhat cheating lol. In my situation, the copy is needed, but this could be considered the solution in other cases.